# How can i return the value of the Button which was pressed

Tags: java, loops, javafx, eventhandler

Hi i know this should be Basics but im realy Stuck
I want to return the int vaue of the button which is clicked and close the dialog

```
public static int showButtonDialog(String title, String label, String[] button)
{
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    Stage dialog = new Stage();

    boolean value = false;
    GridPane pain = new GridPane();
    Scene layer = new Scene(pain);
    dialog.setScene(layer);
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    pain.add(new Label(label), 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
    {
        final int finalI = i;

        buttons.add(new Button(button[i].toString()));
        pain.add((buttons.get(i)), i, 1);

        buttons.get(i).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                changeint(finalI);
                change(value);
                dialog.close();
            }

        });

    }
    dialog.showAndWait();
    if (value)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

But how can i make the method handle return an int its an override method.

Comment: You can't. The `handle` method is `void`. Where would you receive the returned value anyway?

Comment: @James_D Is right, the `handle()` method is void

Comment: but how is it realizable to return the value of the button i clicked its such an simple problem I already tried to write another method in the inner anonymous class but he only start handle which doesnt return something... I also wonder why my questions gets downvoted yes i now im begginer with simple question...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to return a value from that method. You never call that method (it is called by the FX framework), so you would never be able to use the returned value anyway. I downvoted the question because it is unclear what you are asking. This is essentially an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378): you are asking to fix the wrong solution to a problem, but haven't actually explained the problem (just the wrong solution). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Instead of returning a value from the `handle` method, you just call another method `button.setOnAction(event->doSomeThingMethod());`

Comment: I even made kind of Pseudocode what i wanted to do :)
If i click the button the buttons are in arrays list i want to close the stage and return the value of the index which is the button

Example Button2 in arraylist index=1
I click this Button stage.close() and my method in which this is return 1 (the index)
If i close the stage with the [X] top left i return -1

Comment: OK, but why are you doing that? ***Nowhere in your code do you ever call `handle(...)`***, so, even if you could return a value, you would never be able to do anything with it. Why do you think you want to do this? It makes no sense.

Comment: @Mralladdin I think what James_D is saying is you can't return the value from a void method, so what were you planning on doing after returning it? Show it on the screen, write it to a file, or ...? Complete, compiling code, even if not functioning as you want, might be helpful if it's easy for you to extract.

Comment: This is the complete Method its a static method wich creates Stages and on click on a button it closes the stage and return the value of the button. On other close actions than buttonclick for example [X] top right it return -1. I want to use the Methode in other classes

http://pastebin.com/eLZhjz9u

Comment: @Mralladin, I hate to give you bad news, but this method will never return the value you want it to. Its job is to set up the EventHandlers and then return immediately, it will return before the button is even pressed. So you have to rethink your code, and do what you want to do by calling a method when the button is pressed, please see Colns Abt's comment above, or my answer below, for some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: @IanLovejoy Part of what I'm saying is that it's impossible to return a value from `handle`. The other part (actually the main part) of what I'm saying is that it doesn't make any sense to do so. Since you ***never call `handle`*** in your code, even if you could return a value you would never get a chance to do anything with the returned value.

Comment: @James_D totally with you, everything you've said is correct. What I have tried to do is give some additional conceptual hints that might help Mralladin understand how to ask a more well-defined question, and/or come up with the solution on his own.

Comment: I tested some around yes you were right what a dumb mistake from me but thx guys for the help i will test around and if interested i can post the answear here

Comment: @Mralladin So the question you are asking is not "how do I return a value from `handle`". The question you are asking should be "How do I return a value from this `showButtonDialog` that indicates the button that was pressed?". Your proposed solution (return a value from the `handle` method) wouldn't do this even if it were possible. [Edit] your question to indicate what you are really asking, with the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

-You need to create a final copy of the mutable variable i in order to reference it in your code

```
final int finalI = i;
buttons.get(i).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
... the rest of your code...
```

-As was helpfully pointed out by James_D, you can't return a value from handle() because it returns void. You probably want to invoke a method of your class with the value instead:

```
...(inside your event handler)...
doButtonClickAction(finalI);
```

Good luck!

Comment: I assume you didn't actually try that code. It won't compile.

Comment: Of course, because neither would the original code - conceptual input, therefore conceptual output, but illustrating how one can use the current value of a mutable variable within an inner class. However I missed your comment pointing out that the return type of the method is actually void, so I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value in your button handler methods, and return that value from your `showButtonDialog` method. Since you are calling `showAndWait()`, execution will stop at that point, which will allow the value to be set before the method returns.

The only tricky part here is that you can't modify a local variable from within a lambda expression, so you need to create a wrapper class to hold the value. The least verbose approach is a local inner class:

```
public static int showButtonDialog(String title, String label, String[] button)
{
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    Stage dialog = new Stage();

    boolean value = false;
    GridPane pain = new GridPane();
    Scene layer = new Scene(pain);
    dialog.setScene(layer);
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    pain.add(new Label(label), 0, 0);

    class ValueHolder { int value ; }
    ValueHolder valueHolder = new ValueHolder();
    valueHolder.value = -1 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
    {
        final int finalI = i;

        buttons.add(new Button(button[i].toString()));
        pain.add((buttons.get(i)), i, 1);

        buttons.get(i).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                valueHolder.value = finalI ;
                dialog.close();
            }

        });

    }
    dialog.showAndWait();
    return valueHolder.value ;
}
```

Note here that you are really replicating some of the functionality of the [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class: it may well be better just to use that class instead of creating your own dialog.